# Mongoose: Creating a new subdocument (part of a nested schema) with it's default values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple problem that I am facing, unable to find any solution online. I have a mongoose schema that contains a nested schema.

```js
const Person = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true, default: 'John Smith' },
        age: { type: Number, required: false },
        hobbies: { type: [HobbiesSchema], required: false, default: undefined },
    }
);

const HobbiesSchema = new Schema(
    {
        hobby: { type: String, required: true, default: 'Football' }
    }
);
```

Let's say I wanted to create a new Person with it's default values, that's pretty easy.

```js
const person = new Person({});
// results in: { name: 'John Smith' }
```

But what if I wanted to create just a new `hobby` object for that person. Now, that can easily be handled by mongoose if you define your default values like this:

```js
// for single nested object
hobbies: { type: [HobbiesSchema], required: false, default: default: () => ({}) },
// for array of objects
hobbies: { type: [HobbiesSchema], required: false, default: default: () => ([]) },
```

The problem here is that even if you set it to `required: false`, it still inserts default values when you create a new model instance which is undesired behavior for me.

I am aware that `setDefaultsOnInsert` exists, however I am working with bulk operations so that is not an option for me.

So what I am hoping to find is some way or a workaround to create something like this:

```js
const hobby = new Person.Hobbies({}); // pseudo-code
// result: { hobby: 'Football' }
```

I need just that object.

---

**Solution:**

Okay, I managed to find a solution:

```js
const hobby = Person.schema.path('hobbies').cast({});
// result: { hobby: 'football' }
```

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9076#issuecomment-646185905